# Is it useful to list the c/c++ source file in the prerequisites for the %.o target in the recommended Auto-Dependency Generation with makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am referring to the advanced method for [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) recommended for GNU make+gcc. I could have asked on the Mad Scientist website, but the author is very active on SO.

In that method, the chain of dependencies for the target "%.o" is summarized in these lines:

```
%.o : %.cxx $(DEPDIR)/%.d
        $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
        $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))
```

From my understanding of GNU make and from some basic experimentation, it seems to me that having the "%.cxx" in the list of prerequisites for the targert "%.o" is unnecessary and redundant. We could have the exact same behavior with:

```
%.o : $(DEPDIR)/%.d
        $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $*.cxx
        $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))
```

The rationale is that the dependency file explicitly lists the source file as a prerequisite for the object file. Of course, all aspects of the brilliant analysis in the original page still stand (e.g. the built-in rules might need to be deleted, the missing dependency file will trigger the rule for the object file anyway, etc.)

It might seem like a trivial change but there is a significant implication: the list of prerequisites for a target object file built from a C source file would be exactly the same as a target object file built from a C++ source file or any other compiled language, which could enable delegating more work into some macros and have only one rule for all compiled languages:

```
%.o: %.d
        $(COMPILE) $(OUTPUT_OPTIONS) $(SOURCE)
        $(POSTCOMPILE)
```

The macros COMPILE, OUTPUT_OPTIONS and SOURCE could use any combination of target-specific values and analysis of $* to get the job done.

So, the question is: **In this context, besides identifying the language used in the source file, is it useful to list the source file (in addition to the dependency file) in the list of prerequisites for the target object file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It might seem like a trivial change but there is a significant implication: the list of prerequisites for a target object file built from a C source file would be exactly the same as a target object file built from a C++ source file or any other compiled language

Well, I'm not sure what languages besides C/C++ you mean.

> The macros COMPILE, OUTPUT_OPTIONS and SOURCE could use any combination of target-specific values and analysis of $* to get the job done.

I believe it will be less convenient than simply having a couple of distinct rules. So, even if your proposition will work okay, I don't see any practical reason to do this.

Considering possible problems, I can see at least one: if $*.cxx is an auto-generated file then it won't work at all, as you effectively break any implicit rules chaining.

Comment: Breaking the auto-generation is indeed a real possibility. Thanks a lot Matt

Answer (score 1):

The other way around is the correct way:

```
%.o : %.cxx
```

That is because you want `.o` to be rebuilt when `.cxx` has been edited. One never edits `.d` files.

And no dependency on `%.d`.

However, when `%.d` is included into the makefile, makefiles becomes dependant on that `.d` and tries to update it, so that you still need that empty `$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;` rule.

The first time a build is done no dependencies are necessary because everything needs to be build. The next build the dependencies are used to determine what needs to be rebuild.

A more straightforward way is to have all dependency files right next to the corresponding `.o` files, in the same directory. Because different build modes (debug/release) may have different includes (each build mode must have its own output directory, so that you can switch between the modes without having to do `make clean` first). The example of handling dependencies in that article should not be followed, in my opinion.

Comment: The %.d prerequisite was added for a very good reason: it sometimes gets deleted accidentally. When this happens, without the %.d prerequisite you would need another mechanism to ensure that it gets rebuilt

Comment: @ComeRaczy I don't think so. If you delete random files accidentally that is a different problem. May be you need backups.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Unfortunately, that's not a very practical solution. For good or for bad, Make is still a default build tool for many source-based distributions. Of course, a spherical developer in free space may do anything with his own PC, but a general recipe for handling dependencies must be bulletproof. So your way might suit your personal needs, but it's not "the correct one".

Comment: @Matt By "correct" I mean that `.o` **must** depend on `.cxx`. I do not think your accidental file deletions is something a build system should handle. Feel free to disagree.